# OS X app that works without being active?

Tags: macos, cocoa

Recently i've tried [ColorSnapper](http://colorsnapper.com/) app, and I've noticed that it works keeping other applications active.

(Check the screen below, as you can see safari window is still active and ColorSnapper keeps being active too).

[image]

How can is possible reproduce this effect ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe these types of apps use `LSBackgroundOnly` or `LSUIElement` as Launch Services keys in their plist files ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html)).

[Here's](http://uselessthingies.wordpress.com/2008/05/18/an-app-without-dock-icon-and-menu-bar/) a bit more about it.

Comment: I'm sure it uses LSUIElement because it doesn't appear in the dock menu... i'll check for LSBackgroudOnly!

Comment: I tried with a new combination... LSBackgroundOnly and hud as window mode. This set keeps other applications active but it doesn't work with Photoshop... it still closing its windows when I open my app.

Answer (score 2):

I just try it and **LSBackgroundOnly** is the solution, but you must set the level of the window.

Example :

```
[mySpecialNSWindow setLevel:NSMainMenuWindowLevel];
```

This will display the special window above the windows of other applications.

Comment: The problem isn't display a window over the others, but make the other windows keeps their active states.

Answer (score 1):

I think the right approach is a mixture of (1) making the app LSBackgroundOnly, (2) using a custom transparent window as described [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/drawing-custom-window-on-mac-os-x.html) and set its level to NSFloatingWindowLevel, (3) using something like this in your app delegate to monitor mouse movements though your app is not active and, for example, to let your window follow the mouse position:

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSMouseMovedMask handler:^(NSEvent *event) {
        [window setFrameOrigin:[NSEvent mouseLocation]];
    }];
```

You can then have views as you like in the (transparent) window, move them around and modify its contents according to the mouse position.